# Find solution of $(f(x))^3 – 3f(x) + x = 0$

Tags: calculus

If $f(x)$ is differentiable function and $(f(x))^3 – 3f(x) + x = 0$, where $f(x) ≠ 1$, then the value of $|9f'(2)|$ is______

My approach is as follow

$f'(x)3(f(x))^2 – 3f'(x) + 1 = 0$

$f'(x)=\frac{-1}{3(f(x))^2 – 3}$

How do I proceed from here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put $y=f(2)$. Then $0=y^3-3y+2=(y+2)(y-1)^2$. Since $y  \neq 1$, we see that $y=-2$. Therefore, $f'(2)=- \frac{1}{9}$ and the answer to fill in the blank is $1$.

Comment: Don't you mean $y = -2$?

Comment: I just fixed it. The result is the same.

Comment: Roots of $x^3-3x+2$ are 1,1,-2

Answer (score 2):

Let $y = f(2)$

You have the cubic $y^3 -3y + 2 = 0$.

It has one obvious very nice root (which will need to be excluded because of the stipulation in the question, but it still helps in factorisation). Solve it and substitute for $f(2)$ and you should get a quick answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you know that $$(1)\; f'(x)=\frac{-1}{3(f(x))^2 – 3}$$, and that $f(2)^3-3f(2)+2=0$, then just calculate the only factible real root of $x^3-3x+2$ and plug it in $(1)$

Comment: There are at least $2$ nice real roots, it's just that one has to be excluded based on given conditions.

Comment: yeah, thanks! While solving the equation i forgot the $3$ multiplying the $x$